# No sound output - Ubuntu 17.10 - ASUS Zenbook 13

Tags: sound, 17.10, asus

I bought a new Zenbook 13 and installed Ubuntu 17.10.
Unfortunately, I can not get any sound output (neither internal speaker nor headphones). It is a dual boot system and the sound just works fine in Windows 10.
Already tested GNOME ALSA Mixer but it was not successful.
Hope someone can help.

Output of `uname -r`:

```
4.13.0-19-generic
```

Output of `cat /proc/asound/cards`:

```
0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH<br>
                  HDA Intel PCH at 0xef328000 irq 283
```

Output of `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC294 Analog [ALC294 Analog]
 Subdevices: 0/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Output of `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav`:

```
Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, >Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
```

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 audio`:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d71] (rev 21)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1cd0]
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Output of `ps -C esd`:

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
```

Output of `ps -C arts`:

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
```

Output of `ps -C pulseaudio`:

```
 PID TTY          TIME CMD
1118 ?        00:00:00 pulseaudio
1385 ?        00:00:35 pulseaudio
```

Output of `grep "^audio" /etc/group | grep "$USER" | wc -l`:

```
1
```

Output of `dpkg -l | tr -s " " | grep " alsa-"`:

```
ii alsa-base 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5 all ALSA driver configuration files
ii alsa-utils 1.1.3-1ubuntu1 amd64 Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
```

Comment: I just started Ubuntu and suddenly the sound works. Since my post yesterday I rebooted multiple times, switched from Windows (gaming) to Ubuntu and back but did not do any changes to my system. I hope it just works from now on even though I would to know what caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I had a few more days to experiment I found kind of a solution for my situation: When I run Windows 10 and restart the computer to switch to Ubuntu the sound seems to always disappear. However if I turn the computer off and then switch it on and load Ubuntu the sound seems to work. Still do not really understand what is causing the issue.

Comment: I had a similar issue on Dell Vostro 5568 : [Sound card not recognized on Dell Vostro 5568](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1636905). Not sure if it is related.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the linux alsa driver doesn't know how to deal with this sound card correctly.

More details here
[No sound in Ubuntu 18.04 after rebooting from windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032543/no-sound-in-ubuntu-18-04-after-rebooting-from-windows-10)