# No sound in Ubuntu 18.04 after rebooting from windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm on 18.04 in a Asus Zenbook laptop and my sound works fine after a shutdown (clean slate). If I boot into ubuntu, sound works, if i reboot still into ubuntu, sound still works. If I boot into Windows 10 and then shut down and boot into ubuntu, sound works. But if I boot into windows 10 and then *reboot* into ubuntu, now the sound doesn't work (nothing is muted in `alsamixer` but there is no sound at all). Only a shutdown fixes it, reboots don't. 
I already disabled fast boot in windows and killed/cleaned pulse audio as suggested in [all these other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464388/no-sound-from-laptop-speakers-in-ubuntu-14-04-after-booting-into-windows-8-1) answers. Sound doesn't work on headphones either

I took two syslog snapshots when sound works and when it doesn't and I don't see any significant differences between them. It really looks to me like a hardware/firmware issue but I imagine there must be a way to fix it from software. Any suggestions?

```
hilikus@developorium:~$ grep -C 3 snd no-sound-after-reboot  
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.229033] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.232083] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.232086] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.235334] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.235547] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam (13d3:5694)
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.244124] uvcvideo 1-6:1.0: Entity type for entity Realtek Extended Controls Unit was not initialized!
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.244126] uvcvideo 1-6:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
--
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.416112] thermal thermal_zone6: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.417112] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.804303] [drm] RC6 on
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.832374] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.861595] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC294: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.861597] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.861598] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.861599] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.861600] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.861601] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x12
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.915132] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input11
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.915169] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input12
May  5  developorium kernel: [    3.915200] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13
```

Comment: The only time I had similar issues, I installed PulseAudio Volume Control, and that alone fixed it (of course when I opened the app and tweaked a little here and there). Do you have it installed?

Comment: As per your own answer, it is a bug. Bug reports are off topic here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This ended up being a bug in the Realtek ALC294 alsa driver. It has been already reported in launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1742852

Upvote it if it affects you so that devs increase its priority

Answer (score 4):

Windows is notorious for shutting off devices when rebooting and then powering them back on after rebooting. This is particularly problematic with Network cards but as your question illustrates it happens with sound cards as well.

From this [Dell forum](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General/XPS-13-2015-Win10-Sound-breaks-after-wake-restart/td-p/4675699) other users suffer the same fate. As stated you you can:

- reboot into Windows 10
- select shutdown
- cold boot your system with power button
- select Ubuntu

You can save time by suspending and resuming your Ubuntu 16.04 as one of the answer in [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1660371&page=2) describes.

### Summary

You can't reboot Windows and select Ubuntu from Grub menu. You have to shutdown and hit power button as per the links above. You could visit the Dell links and post a request for a Linux utility to power on the device.

The best solution may be to post a Windows question in [Super User](https://superuser.com/) asking how to change Windows not to power off sound card during reboot.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. it will help me research more  a solution knowing that the problem seems to be the windows audio driver. However, there are no solutions in your answer. Your solution of cold booting was already in my question, and I don't even need to boot into windows. any complete shutdown followed by linux boot fixes the issue, but not being able to reboot from win to linux with proper audio is the problem i'm trying to solve

Comment: also, which logs should i compare? as i mentioned, i compared already the syslog and they were the same between working and not working bootups

Comment: @Hilikus You can't reboot you have to cold boot as per the links in the answer. You could visit the Dell links and post a request for a utility to power on the device. The best solution may be to post a Windows question in Super User asking how to change Windows not to power off sound card during reboot. I've updated the answer with this comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change that, telling your BIOS that you have another OS rather than Windows.
 
Open a command prompt and edit the file, with `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
in the line that says `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` add the parameter `acpi_osi=Linux`
So it will be just like this `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux`, with that your Linux OS will take more control in your computer.
[Suggested reading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28848/what-does-the-kernel-boot-parameter-set-acpi-osi-linux-do)

Comment: I'm posting a solution but using windows, but wait a few hours... I'm downloading :P

Comment: maybe you hate as much as me, that the clock brokens every time you boot windows, read https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/time#UTC_in_Windows for fixing that

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't work. it made no difference

Comment: @Hilikus did you update the grub?

Comment: i didn't do i permanently in the file like you suggested. i did it by editing the grub entry directly in grub at bootup and then confirmed that the kernel argument was taken by running `cat /proc/cmdline`. So no need to update grub

Comment: every time you edit the grub... you must update, just type `sudo update-grub` your argument is invalid, please read grub doc

Comment: i think you didn't understand what I said. I didn't need to do that because I didn't persist the change